# Trying to compile libgcrypt 1.5.0 with MinGW32 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw32

I have attempted compiling libgcrypt 1.5.0 with MinGW32 on Windows 7 to no avail. I have already installed the GCC C/C++ compiler and binutils as part of MinGW32, but when I enter `autogen.sh --build-w32` it tells me that there is no cross compiler kit installed...?

Despite searching around for answers, I still do not have a clue as to what is going on. How on earth do you compile libgcrypt with MinGW32? And why is it so stupidly difficult? Most standard libs usually provide a Visual Studio project, but the only Visual Studio project I can find for libgcrypt is extremely dated (1.2.2).

Comment: Were you using Cygwin?  I got it working using Cygwin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The --build-w32 switch is for compiling for Windows on Linux. The readme doesn't mention compiling for Windows on Windows.

I would say try autogen.sh with no arguments and hope it works.

If that doesn't work, install Linux I guess. :/

Comment: It didn't work =( It's almost as if all the GNU projects I've encountered intentionally make it difficult to build on Windows, forcing you to acquire some Linux distro to get it working. I'll probably use a friend's Linux box. Thanks!